# gradle zip task only creates zip in configuration phase

Tags: gradle, zip, lifecycle, execution

When I try to create a zip file in the execution phase of a Zip typed gradle task no zip file is created.
If I perform the same in the configuration phase (leaving out the doLast statement), the zip file is created without problems.
The doLast block is called since the println statement is shown in the output logging.

The reason that we need to generate the zip in the execution phase is because the file which needs to be compressed is the result of the compile execution.
I have also tried to solve this with a jar task, but this gives me similar problems.

Here's the code:

```
    task createClassPathJar(type: Zip) {
  dependsOn("createManifest")

    from("${projectRoot}") {
        include "MANIFEST.MF"
    }
    archiveName = "dummy.jar"

    doLast {

    destinationDir(file("${projectRoot}"))

    archiveName = "zipfile.jar"

    println "executing phase createClassPathJar. archiveName: " + archiveName
  }
}
```

Can someone help me here ? I'm using Gradle v6.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `doLast` to configure the action of your task, because it will be executed **after** the particular action (in this case the zipping) has run. Either use a `doFirst` closure or setup your task configuration in a way that it does not depend on other configurations:

As an example, depending on how properly your task `createManifest` defines its output, you may use it directly to define the `Zip` task content using "`from createManifest`".

I guess your reason for using a `doLast` closure is the call to `destinationDir` that is based on a variable. Instead, you may just use a closure that evaluates the variable lazily:

```
task createManifest {
   outputs.file('path/to/MANIFEST.MF')
}

task createClassPathJar(type: Zip) {
    from createManifest
    archiveName = 'zipfile.jar'
    destinationDir = file({ "${projectRoot}" }) // or just file({ projectRoot })
}
```

Comment: The reason that I need the doFirst / doLast closure is that the manifest file was created in the execution phase. If the zip is created in the configuration phase, the manifest is not yet created.

Comment: Every task is **always** executed during *execution phase*. My example is just a more elegant way to configure the task and should be preferred over using `doFirst` / `doLast` closures.

Comment: This is interesting, indeed the createManifest task now is called by the createClassPathJar task. What do you mean with "depending on how properly your task createManifest defines its output"? How can I instruct the createManifest task to return the file?

Comment: Is the type of the task provided by Gradle or did you implement it on your own? If it's provided by Gradle, then it defines its output properly by default.

Comment: I created the task myself. Is there a way to define the output of a self-defined task?
Thanks for your helping me, I am really struggling with this issue.

Comment: Check out this [section of the Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks). Your task needs to define a file property with the annotation `@OutputFile`.

Comment: Ok, now I understand that this type of issue can only be fixed with a custom task class. I will look into that. It is unfortunate that gradle is not flexible enough to influence the inputs / outputs in a script. Thanks for your help!

Comment: See my edited post on how to define the task output directly in the build script.

Comment: Thanks Lukas, it works! This solution not only solved my problem, but also provides a better understanding of the incremental build mechanism. Until now, I was not aware that the outputs could be implemented in the gradle task configuration. While diving deaper in this issue, I came across an article describing this mechanism: https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-incremental-build-support

Comment: Had a similar requirement - except that I have some subprojects which generate some artifacts at the end of their builds, and I need to zip them up. So, zipping up dynamically after execution of subprojects build - is it even possible?

Comment: @coder This should not be problematic at all. Tasks may depend on tasks of other subprojects, both explicitly (via `dependsOn`) or implicitly by referencing the task (outputs) as inputs for another task (via `from` in a `Zip` or `Copy` task). If you encounter any issues, feel free to open another question.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `doFirst` instead of `doLast`:

```
task createClassPathJar(type: Zip) {
  dependsOn("createManifest")
  from("${projectRoot}") {
    include "MANIFEST.MF"
  }
  archiveName = "dummy.jar"
  doFirst {
    destinationDir(file("${projectRoot}"))
    archiveName = "zipfile.jar"
    println "executing phase createClassPathJar. archiveName: " + archiveName
  }
}
```

I don't know about your case but I tried myself by changing the archive name to the current time in the `doFirst` block, and the archive name was effectively matching the time of execution and not of configuration.

Comment: I tested your solution, at first this seemed to solve the problem. However, If I delete the zip file and the manifest and run the scripts again, the manifest is created, but the createClassPathJar gets status UP-TO-DATE, so the zipfile.jar is not recreated. Can you explain this behaviour?